# Possible to use FlashMessenger without redirect?

Tags: zend-framework

I wonder if its possible to use flash messenger without redirect? eg. After a failed login, I want to continue to display the form, no redirect required.

```
public function loginAction() {
  $form = new Application_Form_Login();

  ...

  if ($this->getRequest()->isPost() && $form->isValid($this->getRequest()->getParams())) {
    $authAdapter = new Application_Auth_Adapter($form->getValue('username'), $form->getValue('password'));
    if ($this->auth->authenticate($authAdapter)->isValid()) {
      ...
    } else {
      // login failed
      $this->flashMessenger->addMessage('Login failed. You may have entered an invalid username and/or password. Try again');
    }
  }

  $this->view->form = $form;
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can retrieve flash messages without redirect using $this->flashMessenger->getCurrentMessages();
Example:

```
$this->view->messages = array_merge(
    $this->_helper->flashMessenger->getMessages(),
    $this->_helper->flashMessenger->getCurrentMessages()
);
$this->_helper->flashMessenger->clearCurrentMessages();
```

Comment: Actually you don't even have to use FMer at all. You can just write $this->view->messages = array('my message', 'my message 2');

Comment: Is there no way to `setCurrentMessages()`? I don't want to always display all messages.

Comment: Messages is added by addMessage() function only. The differenct between getMessages() and getCurrentMessages() is that the former is used to get messages that was saved on previous page before redirect and the latter can retrieve messages that was set during current page processing.

Answer (score 3):

Sure, you can. But I usually attach the auth-failure message to the form itself. In fact, even when the form-level validation fails, I like to display something like "Please note the errors below". So, I treat those two cases separately:

```
public function loginAction()
{
    $form = new Application_Form_Login();
    if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()){
        if ($form->isValid($this->getRequest()->getPost())){
            $username = $form->getValue('username');
            $userpass = $form->getValue('userpass');
            $adapter = new Application_Model_AuthAdapter($username, $userpass);
            $result = $this->_auth->authenticate($adapter);
            if ($result->isValid()){
                // Success.
                // Redirect...
            } else {
                $form->setErrors(array('Invalid user/pass'));
                $form->addDecorator('Errors', array('placement' => 'prepend'));
            }
        } else {
            $form->setErrors(array('Please note the errors below'));
            $form->addDecorator('Errors', array('placement' => 'prepend'));
        }
    }
    $this->view->form = $form;
}
```

Comment: How can I? With my above code, flash messenger messages only show after a refresh

Comment: This is one of the things that I don't like about the FlashMessenger; it only resides at the controller level. To me, this flash messenger business should be a view-centered process. That's why I largely use a view helper called [priorityMessenger](http://emanaton.com/code/php/zendprioritymessenger). To make the existing FlashMessenger useful, you could look at [Robert Basic's FlashMessenger view helper](https://github.com/robertbasic/phpplaneta/blob/master/library/PPN/View/Helper/FlashMessenger.php). In your case, with no refresh, I still think it's simpler to attach errors to the form.