# Zend 2.2 form submit success message using flashMessenger?

Tags: php, forms, zend-framework

I am trying to do simple contact us page with flashmessenger helper plugin.

I have implemented it as below, but my problem is i have to submit the form twice to get the flashmessagers showing in the page.

What i am i doing wrong here ..

1. show the messages on the first submit ?
2. how do i hide the form the after submit ?

in my controller

```
 // Add content to this method:
    public function contactAction()
    {
        $form = new ContactForm();
        $form->get('submit')->setValue('Submit');


        $request = $this->getRequest();
        if ($request->isPost()) {
            $contact = new Contact();
            $form->setInputFilter($contact->getInputFilter());
            $form->setData($request->getPost());

            if ($form->isValid()) {

                $data=$form->getData();
                //var_dump($data);

                $mail = new Mail\Message();
                $mail->setBody($data['comment'])
                     ->setFrom($data['email'], $data['name'])
                     ->addTo(IEMAIL, COMPANY )
                     ->addReplyTo($data['email'], $data['name'])
                     ->setSubject($data['subject']);

                $transport = new Mail\Transport\Sendmail();
                $transport->send($mail);    
                $this->flashMessenger()->addMessage('Thanks you for the submission ');
            }
            else{
                $this->flashMessenger()->addMessage('Opps somethinge went wrong ..!');  
            }
        }
        /**/
        return new ViewModel(array(
            'customMessage' => 'Welcome to the sales',
            'form' => $form
        ));
    }
```

IN my view i have the coding as

```
<?php
$title = 'Contact Us';
$this->headTitle($title);
?>
<h1><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($title); ?></h1>
<?php echo $this->customMessage ?>
<?php
 if ($this->flashMessenger()->hasMessages()): 

 echo $this->flashMessenger()->render('success', array('alert', 'alert-danger'));
 // In any of your .phtml files:
 $flash = $this->flashMessenger();
 $flash->setMessageOpenFormat('<div%s>
     <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">
         &times;
     </button>
     <ul><li>')
     ->setMessageSeparatorString('</li><li>')
     ->setMessageCloseString('</li></ul></div>');

 echo $flash->render('error',   array('alert', 'alert-dismissable', 'alert-danger'));
 echo $flash->render('info',    array('alert', 'alert-dismissable', 'alert-info'));
 echo $flash->render('default', array('alert', 'alert-dismissable', 'alert-warning'));
 echo $flash->render('success', array('alert', 'alert-dismissable', 'alert-success'));
?>
<? endif ?>
<?php
$form->setAttribute('action', $this->url('contact', array('action' => 'submit')));
$form->prepare();

echo $this->form()->openTag($form);
echo $this->formRow($form->get('name'));
echo $this->formRow($form->get('email'));
echo $this->formRow($form->get('subject'));
echo $this->formRow($form->get('comment'));
echo $this->formSubmit($form->get('submit'));
echo $this->form()->closeTag();
```

Comment: 1. Check you session container http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.2/en/modules/zend.mvc.plugins.html#zend-mvc-controller-plugins-flashmessenger                                                        2. When you have valid post data set the 'form' => ''

Comment: i think last part cutoff, not clear what do you mean by this " post data set the 'form' => ' ?

Comment: When you have valid post data $form->isValid() set the  return new ViewModel(array(
            'customMessage' => 'Thank you for submit',
            'form' => ''
        ));

Comment: still something wrong logically for some reason i have submit the form twice to get the correct message .. not sure why

Comment: What is this colon at the end of ur code ? if ($this->flashMessenger()->hasMessages()):

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The flash messenger does not work in the way you are expecting. It is designed for showing messages to the user after a redirect. To do this it adds any messages you pass to it to a session container so they can be retrieved on the next request. This behaviour ([Post/Redirect/Get](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get)) is a common pattern in web applications as it reduces of the chance of a user accidentally re-submitting form submissions by refreshing the page.

If you add a redirect after your `$transport->send($mail);`, then the successful submissions should work how you expect. For the failed ones to work you'll need to write your own helper that does same-request messaging as well (which is what I normally do). Instead you might want to get rid of the fail message and just let the form's inbuilt error messaging do its thing.

Comment: so what it is the zend recommended way of doing this simple form submit and then show the messages ...etc (i am very new to zend)

Comment: I've edited my answer. I'd suggest adding a redirect after the transport send and just removing your 'Oops' message for now.

Comment: hey @mahen3d look at the following link
[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4516704/possible-to-use-flashmessenger-without-redirect)

Answer (score 0):

```
Change this code in controller...

            $message    = '';
    $flashMessenger = $this->flashMessenger();
    if ($flashMessenger->hasMessages()) {
        $message = $flashMessenger->getMessages();
    }
```

And in View

```
             <?php if(is_array($message) && count($message) > 0){
            foreach($message as $messageKey => $messageValue){?>
            <div style= "color:red"> <?php echo $messageValue; ?> </div>
        <?php } } ?>
```